# How do you get the Type of any basic system object or primitive

Tags: c#, sql, orm

I'm trying to intelligently populate an object from the results of a SQL query. I'm looping through the results of a `SQLDataReader` and using `GetDataTypeName()` to get the string representation of the data type held in any particular field.

How can I automatically get the `Type` of each field without manually mapping string names to types. I've tried using:

```
Type.GetType(reader.GetDataTypeName(), true, true)
```

(Note, case-sensitivity is ignored)

But `GetDataTypeName()` returns strings of primitives such as like "int" and these throw TypeLoadExceptions for the example given.

I've read that `GetType()` requires an assembly qualified type name so non-primitive system types like DateTime would need to be qualified with "System.DateTime", however simply prefixing the "System" namespace with "int" doesn't help for a primitive type such as this.

Comment: Why would you not just use `reader.GetFieldType(n)` ?

Comment: That returns a **SQL** type name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to parse anything here; just use:

```
Type type = reader.GetFieldType(columnIndex);
```